# Create batch script file using comand prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

how to create batch file.

```
echo off
cls
(
echo TIMEOUT /T 0 > nul|set/p =please wait....
)
> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\test.bat"
exit
```

**output : please wait....**

how to make the output

**TIMEOUT /T 0 > nul|set/p =please wait....** in test.bat

Comment: You're asking how to add the literal string `TIMEOUT /T 0 > nul|set/p =please wait....` to test.bat, right?

Comment: yes @SomethingDark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the special characters so it will not be seen as the operators for the current batch, instead passed to the next batch file.

```
(echo @echo off
echo TIMEOUT /T 0 ^> nul^|set/p =please wait....
)>"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\test.bat"
```